# Returning a value instead of a pointer in Go

Tags: http, go, maps

In the "net/http" package of Go, there is an interface called `ResponseWriter`. This interface has a method called `Header() Header`. Since the `Header` value that `Header()` returns is a value and not a pointer, I assumed the function would not be returning the actual `Header` value that is private to the `ResponseWriter` but rather a copy.

However, this does not appear to be the case. The docs for `ResponseWriter` show `r.Header().Add("key", "value")` to be the proper way to add a header to your http response.

I dug in a little deeper and found the definition for the `Header` type. It is `type Header map[string][]string`. I'm a little confused here. Do you not have to return a pointer in this case in order to modify the value that the `ResponseWriter` has? If so why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because maps and slices are reference types.
Take a look this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    m1 := make(map[string]string)
    var m2 map[string]string
    m1["one"] = "this is from m1"
    m2 = m1
    m2["two"] = "this is from m2"
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", m1)
}
```

The output is:

```
map[string]string{"one":"this is from m1", "two":"this is from m2"}
```

[See/edit in the Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/0g3e0FuXlp).

This has the same result:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type mymap map[string]string

func main() {
    m1 := make(mymap)
    var m2 mymap
    m1["one"] = "this is from m1"
    m2 = m1
    m2["two"] = "this is from m2"
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", m1)
}
```

Output:

```
main.mymap{"one":"this is from m1", "two":"this is from m2"}
```

[See/edit in the Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ZbBOtpzFIo).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Seems correct. I found this which explained thing in a little more detail. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/xQUsmdo6oSs